# What is the use of "yield" in an expression context?

Tags: php, generator, yield

As in the php manual yield can use part of a expression. $data = (yield $value); But it doesn’t assigned anything to $myval. Am i doing something wrong here? How we can use it in a expression?

```
     function test_yield(){
        for ($i=0; $i <10; $i++) { 
             $myval = (yield $i);
             echo " \ ".$myval." / <br />";
        }

    }
    foreach (test_yield() as $value) {
        echo $value;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the PHP [rfc:generators](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generators)

> The return value of the `yield` expression is whatever was sent to the generator using `send()`. If nothing was sent (e.g. during `foreach` iteration) `null` is returned.

Your `foreach` code never [`send()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/generator.send.php)s anything *into* the generator, so `yield` always returns `null`.